# How to calculate average of text field in salesforce reports?

Tags: lightning, dashboard

I have an[image] Average correction requested field which is a formula field that returns days hours and minutes for each case number for example like 24 days 4 hours 0 months, 12 days 6 hours 30 months and I want an average of these days hours and month in report please refer the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the average would be to convert all the dates to milliseconds and getting the average of all those times. Once you have that you can convert it back to a date.

Comment: Please tell me how to convert all the dates to milliseconds and then again convert those milliseconds to d.ate